# Get access token Using Koala and omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api

I have `omniauth-facebook gem` installed and i configured that in `config/initializer/omniauth.rb` (where i mentioned the keys) . I ,now, need to use `koala` alongwith `omniauth-facebook`. I've a `page-id` `(facebook)` and want to retrieve data/posts from that . for that i have code like below

```
app_id = "654654654654"
client_secret = "serwerwere5445654655"
access = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, client_secret) 
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access)       
@feeds = @graph.get_connections(fb_id, "feed")
```

i think i'm missing something very basic , but don't know what !

Note : one point is that i don't want login before retrieving post and want to access `"access_token"` without login using `app_id` , `client_secret`

**2nd:**
 How can i get `app_id` and `secret` defined in `config/initializer/omniauth`

Comment: You could use config/secrets.yml to store your keys. Also note that changing code in app/initializers needs a rails server restart.

Comment: Are you trying to use omniauth-facebook strategy with something like devise?

Comment: @preciz i just simply need to get access key using koala